# Dailogflow Inline Editor Response

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, fulfillment

I am trying to display response from inline editor in google's dialog flow but I am not getting the response.However , all the mandatory entities are already fetched from used.The response which I receive from the bot is "Not available".Below is the code which I am written in index.js file in the fulfillment section and enabled the fulfillment as well for the Intent which I am using.

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment =
    functions.https.onRequest((request,response)=> {
        var chat ="Here is a sample response ,this should actually give you real stock information";
        response.setHeader('Content-type','application/json');
        response.send(JSON.stringify({"speech":chat,"displayText":chat}))
    });
```

Please help me for the same.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you update your question to show any of the logs from the webhook being called, and can you clarify where you're seeing the "Not available" response?

Comment: What version is your Dialogflow agent?

Comment: @matthewayne V2 is the version of dialogflow agent.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you are sending in response is for a v1 agent.  The `speech` and `displayText` attributes have been replaced by `fulfillmentText` in v2.  Replace:

```
response.send(JSON.stringify({"speech":chat,"displayText":chat}))
```

with this

```
response.send(JSON.stringify({fulfillmentText:chat}))
```

Comment: I tried the same but still getting response as "Not Available".

Comment: Sorry, the second code sample should have said `fulfillmentText` not `displayText`.  I've edited my answer to make it correct.  A full example is here: https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-json/blob/master/responses/v2/response.json